# How do i refresh a TableView after some data will changed?

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I want to change the list of users in only one class, called Network. And i don't understand how to make a TableView update after the userList has changed. I'll show you an example and detailed question in code below.

```
// Network.swift
class Network {
    var userList: [User] = []

    // Next functions may change userList array
    // For example, the data came from the server, and update the userList with new data
}

// App delegate
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var network: Network = Network()

    ..
}

// File TableViewController.swift
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    …
    var userList: [User] = [] // Here I want to have a full copy of the array from Network class

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        self.userList = appDelegate.network.userList // Just copy an array
        // And I want that after each update appDelegate.network.userList I updated the table, how to do it better?

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }  
}
```

Comment: Your architecture is pretty unorganized and bad (why hold a var in appdelegate for this) How is this list getting updated? Who's the caller to the network to check for updates?

Answer (score 2):

As @JDM mentioned in comment your architecture is messed.
Try to do this delegation using protocols:

```
// Network.swift
protocol UsersUpdatedProtocol {
  func usersListUpdated(list: [User])
}
class Network {
  var userList: [User] = [] {
    didSet {
      delegate?.usersListUpdated(list: userList)
    }
  }
  var delegate: UsersUpdatedProtocol?
  init(delegate d: UsersUpdatedProtocol) {
    super.init()
    delegate = d
  }
}

// File TableViewController.swift
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UsersUpdatedProtocol {
  var userList: [User] = []

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let _ = Network(delegate: self)
  }
  func usersListUpdated(list: [User]) {
    self.userList = list
    self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution will work if just one thing is going to respond to the update of the user list.  If more than one thing will be responding then you might be better using a notifiation

Answer (score 1):

You could use a notification. Whenever the userlist gets updated, post a notification like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "UserlistUpdate"), object: nil)
```

Then, in viewDidLoad add:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(TableViewController.reloadData), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "UserlistUpdate"), object: nil)
```

P.S. regarding your architecture so far, I would make the TableViewController hold a variable for Network rather than hold its own user array. Then, in AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let network = Network()

    // Access the TableViewController and set its network variable
    let tableViewController = window!.rootViewController as! TableViewController
    tableViewController.network = network
```

Comment: This method would be good if more than one thing can respond to the change in the user list as they can each subscribe to the notification.

Comment: As for the architecture might I suggest a singleton approach: public class `MyClass {

    static let sharedInstance = MyClass()

    private init() {
    }

}`